# Property from another ViewModel doesn't change

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I need to change a value of property `TextSource` from another ViewModel, so I did this to get ReaderViewModel.

**ViewerViewModel.cs**:

```cs
        private ReaderViewModel _readerViewModel = new ReaderViewModel();
        public ReaderViewModel ReaderViewModel
        {
            get => _readerViewModel;
            set
            {
                _readerViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("");
            }
        }
```

As well as changing the property's value to something:

```cs
ReaderViewModel.TextSource = "some string";
```

**ReaderViewModel.cs**:

```cs
        private string _textSource;
        public string TextSource
        {
            get => _textSource;
            set
            {
                _textSource = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

**ReaderPage.xaml**:

```xml
<Page.DataContext>
   <viewModels:ReaderViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

   ...

<Grid>
   <TextBox Text="{Binding TextSource}"/>
<Grid/>
```

But it don't work at all, TextBox is still empty. I can't really figure out, where's the problem. The DataContext for ReaderPage is already set to the right ViewModel.

Comment: What's the `DataContext` of `ReaderPage` and how do you set it? Your code sample doesn't tell. As a side note, you shouldn't call `OnPropertyChanged` with an empty `string`.

Comment: As I said, it's already set to `ReaderViewModel`, but ok, I edited the post

Comment: You are creating once instance in the view and another one in the `ViewerViewModel`...so the one you set the `TextSource` property of it not the one that the view binds to.

Comment: You can debug bindings with PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High. See e.g. https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/debugging/

Comment: @MaciekŚwiszczowski debugging or adjusting the trace level do say nothing about the binding

Answer (score 4):

> I can't really figure out, where's the problem

You are creating one instance of the `ReaderViewModel` in the view:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <viewModels:ReaderViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

...and another one in the `ViewerViewModel`:

```
private ReaderViewModel _readerViewModel = new ReaderViewModel();
```

Setting the `TextSource` property of the latter instance won't affect the view that is bound to the former instance.

You should make sure that there is only one instance of the `ReaderViewModel` involved.